# Get order object inside email_order_set_template_vars_before event observer

Tags: magento2, event-observer, email-templates

I have observer for **email_order_set_template_vars_before** where i am setting some email template variable to use in order confirmation email.

Now i want to find which products customer has ordered in that order and depending on that set value for email template variable.

So how can i access order object inside this observer method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found answer myself. Sharing here so it may help someone.

We can get Order object inside execute method of observer as below:

```
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {

        $transport = $observer->getTransport();
        $order=$transport['order'];
        $orderId=$order->getEntityId(); /** We can call any method of $order as usual **/

    }
```

Comment: How to get shipping information?

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code to get order data

```
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
{
    $transport = $observer->getTransport();
    $order = $transport->getData('order');
    $orderId = $order->getId();
}
```